# How to load javascript after click in to another url

Tags: javascript

How can i add this JS into a link:

1. Im in page1.php;
2. I need click in some link Link
   And when i go to page2.php some code load this JS:

javascript:void(lz_chat_change_state(true,false));

Any help?
It seems to be simple but not for me......

Answer (score 1):

Solved !

If page1 has ?chat i execute the javascript in page2;

Link in page1.php?chat

In page2.php

```
if (isset($_GET['chat'])) {
    include_once("js-externo.php");
}else{
    // Fallback behaviour goes here
}
```

In file js-externo.php i put:

```
window.onload = function() {
void(lz_chat_change_state(true,false));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to call that function when you click on the link?
If yes 
Make javascript file seperate.
Inside the link you put a "onclick" event and call the javascript function as:

```
<a href="page2.php" onclick = "lz_chat_change_state('true','false')">
```

If you want things to change after going to page2.php particularly then you need to use sessions. Pass a value from page1 to page2. But looking at your function (which I assume is being used as a toggle) it's not necessary.

Comment: Hi, Bishwas, thanks for reply. But dont work... I think the "onclick" stay in page1. When page2 was load nothing happend... Any other idea please?

Comment: Yes Max. Onclick event will do some toggling if and only if you have an external javascript file. So that when second page is loaded the status is fetched from the .js file directly. Are we on the same track? Or are you trying to achieve something else?